# TinyMCE in frontend on WordPress With Timber/Twigg template

Tags: wordpress, twig, tinymce

I am trying to add a wysiwyg editor to a page of my site on a form. I tried these 2 ways but each time I only have a basic textarea without the toolbar or anything.

**1st Way**

```
{% extends "twig/layout/base.twig" %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>

    <script>
      tinymce.init({
        selector: '#mytextarea'
      });
    </script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{#  code before  #}

                            <div class="form-group double required">
                                <label for="description">{{ post.get_field('label_description') }}</label>
                                <textarea id="mytextarea" tabindex="-1" name="description" class="form-control input-description" placeholder="{{ post.get_field('placeholder_description') }}" rows="6" minlength="1" required></textarea>
                            </div>

{#  code after  #}      

{% endblock %}
```

**2nd Way**

```
{% extends "twig/layout/base.twig" %}

{% block javascripts %}
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector :"tinymce-enabled"
    });
</script>

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{#  code before  #}

                            <div class="form-group double required">
                                <label for="description">{{ post.get_field('label_description') }}</label>
                                <textarea id="mytextarea" tabindex="-1" name="description" class="tinymce-enabled form-control input-description" placeholder="{{ post.get_field('placeholder_description') }}" rows="6" minlength="1" required></textarea>
                            </div>

{#  code after  #}      

{% endblock %}
```

No error in the console ...

Comment: Does `twig/layout/base.twig` actually contains a block called `javascripts`? Verify that the javascript gets injected in the generated source

Comment: @DarkBee your right ! I forget that ...